# Python SQL Server login retry logic if login failed for user

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Python SQL Server login retry logic if login failed for user. I am using this logic in a script, but sometimes it's failing to login to the database.

I want to retry to connect to the database if the connection fails.

```
try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 1):

with this the connection will be retried until success.
do you think there should be limited number of tries?

```
cursor = None
while cursor is None:
    try:
        
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    except:
         pass
```